# Calling Data Model from App.php

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Is there a way I can make a call to a data function function within app.php?

The function I am trying to call is located at src/Project/Model/Data/ImportData.php

Currently the variable is set like so (coming from parameters.yml):

```
$app['active_import_id'] = $config['parameters']['active_import_id'];
```

What I am trying to do:

```
$app['active_import_id'] = $myDataModel->myDataFunction();
```

Comment: Sorry man, I can't understand your problem, if you need to call ```$app['actrive_import_id'] = $myDataModel->myDataFunction()``` why don't you just do this? Can you explain it in another way?

Comment: Got it working, just had to move it to the bottom of the page and added `$myDataModel = $app['project.my_import_data_model'];` Before setting the `$app['active_import_id']` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The application was not initialized, I got it working once I added the code below.

```
$myDataModel = $app['project.my_import_data_model'];
$app['active_import_id'] = $myDataModel->getActiveImportId();
```

I placed this code after all the providers had been registered. Hope this helps someone.